# Authentication failed on sourcetree bitbucket

Tags: push, bitbucket, commit, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using visual studio in order to develop a new project. Using source tree connected to bitbucket it commits successfully. My problem is that when I am trying to push my project it is giving me an authentication error. I tried different paths that I have found through out my search example:

https://git@bitbucket.org/annarapa/tradersmarketplaceapplication.git

https://annarapa@bitbucket.org/annarapa/tradersmarketplaceapplication.git

https://annarapa:mypassword@bitbucket.org/annarapa/tradersmarketplaceapplication.git

all these options give me the same error

[image]

Could you please help me?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? This doesn't look like the official VS2012 or 2013 git client for Visual Studio.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Have you tried whether the standard tools do work? https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c